# How to use ng-repeat for array in array using single ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

I got a json of table which has columns and rows as below

```
$scope.table = {
  Columns: [{Header:"22-Jul-15",SubHeaders: ["10:33 AM"]}
         , {Header:"21-Jul-15",SubHeaders: ["03:40 AM"]}
         , {Header:"17-Jul-15",SubHeaders: ["01:05 PM", "12:06 PM"]}]
 , Rows:[{Items:[{Value:1},{Value:5},{Value:8},{Value:""}]}
       ,{Items:[{Value:2},{Value:6},{Value:9},{Value:""}]}
       ,{Items:[{Value:3},{Value:7},{Value:10},{Value:15}]}]
 } //end of table
```

I want to display `Columns.SubHeaders` as Sub header row of a table.

Here what I tried, but did not work

```
  <table class="table table-stripped table-bordered">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th ng-repeat="col in table.Columns" colspan="{{col.SubHeaders.length}}">{{col.Header}}</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td class="center text-black" ng-repeat="head in table.Columns[0].SubHeaders">{{head}}</td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="row in table.Rows">
                <td ng-repeat="item in row.Items">
                    {{item.Value}}
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

I used `head in table.Columns[0].SubHeaders` just to show it is working for hard-coded index value.

How can I achieve this using single ng-repeat? I can use two ng-repeats but it will lead to unnecessary html markup.

Here is the [complete fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kiranbobade/je7dvu1o/16/)

Comment: Yes, that markup won't work... One thing, your table data (3 columns for each item) doesn't match the column layout (4 columns taking subheaders as the actual columns). How do you plan to match them?

Comment: yes, I created it for demo purpose. I have proper columns in my actual data

Comment: I have updated can you check https://jsfiddle.net/je7dvu1o/17/

Comment: @JayantPatil,  I already tried this, but it works for single sub-header item. there can be multiple sub-headers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created this fiddler (forked from yours):

https://jsfiddle.net/b50hvzef/1/

The idea is to join the subheaders as they are they actual columns:

```
<td class="center text-black" ng-repeat="head in subHeaders">{{head}}</td>
```

and the code looks like this:

```
var app = angular.module("app",[]);
app.controller("MyController", function ($scope, $http) {
$scope.table = {
  Columns: [{Header:"22-Jul-15",SubHeaders: ["10:33 AM"]}
         , {Header:"21-Jul-15",SubHeaders: ["03:40 AM"]}
         , {Header:"17-Jul-15",SubHeaders: ["01:05 PM", "12:06 PM"]}]
 ,Rows:[{Items:[{Value:1},{Value:5},{Value:8}]}
       ,{Items:[{Value:2},{Value:6},{Value:9}]}
       ,{Items:[{Value:3},{Value:7},{Value:10}]}]
    };
var subHeaders = [];
$scope.table.Columns.forEach(function(col) { 
    col.SubHeaders.forEach(function(subHeader) {
        subHeaders.push(subHeader);
    }); 
});
$scope.subHeaders = subHeaders;
```

});

Note that there is still a mismatch between columns and data. But it's up to you how to solve it.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks @Alex, It's perfect now. I could add subHeaders to my table object  so it save my time to do it for each table.